# Button text in winform app

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some buttons on a Winform app, and using the following code have changed their back colour and text.

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();

foreach (Button bt in panel1.Controls)
{
    if (bt is Button)
    {
        buttons.Add(bt);
    }

}

int btext = 1;
foreach (var button in buttons)
{

    button.Text = btext.ToString();
    button.BackColor = Color.White;
    btext++;
}
```

But on viewing the form when its run the button at the bottom right of the grid of buttons has the text "1" and the button at the top left of the grid has the text "36" displayed on it. I was hoping, and thought, that it should be the other way round. Why is it as it is and how do I change it please? Many thanks.

Comment: Ok so all I do  is change the lines int btext =36; and btext --; But I am still non the wiser as to why I need to do this.

Comment: Did you use the designer? Because - as far as I know - the controls are instantiated in alphabetical order. So if you iterate throught the controls of `panel1` you will iterate in alphabetical order over your buttons. That _could_ explain why you have to inverse your loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the order in which controls are added to the `panel1.Controls` collection is relevant here. You can try to set the tab order for the buttons and then sort them by `TabIndex` property.

```
foreach (var bt in panel1.Controls.OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex))
{
    if (bt is Button) 
    {
        buttons.Add(bt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try order by position of the control

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();

foreach (var bt in panel1.Controls)
{
    if (bt is Button)
    {
        buttons.Add((Button)bt);
    }

}

var lst = buttons.OrderBy(x => x.PointToScreen(Point.Empty).Y).ThenBy(x => x.PointToScreen(Point.Empty).X);

int btext = 1;
foreach (var button in lst)
{

    button.Text = btext.ToString();
    button.BackColor = Color.White;
    btext++;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try this LINQ approach:

```
var buttons = panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>()
             .Select((b, i) => new { Button = b, Position = i + 1 });
foreach(var btn in buttons)
{
    btn.Button.Text = btn.Position.ToString();
    btn.Button.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

Or, if you need it the other way around, use `Reverse`:

```
foreach (var btn in buttons.Reverse())
{
    btn.Button.Text = btn.Position.ToString();
    btn.Button.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need order of text labels changed you can do this:

```
List<Button> buttons = panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
buttons.Reverse();

int btext = 1;
foreach (var button in buttons)
{
    button.Text = btext.ToString();
    button.BackColor = Color.White;
    btext++;
}
```